# How to use ActiveJob (Resque Adapter) with Rails no ActiveRecord (using Mongoid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, resque, rails-activejob

I've been using Mongoid Adapter with Rails for an app. So I basically set the project up to not use ActiveRecord (since I'll also be deploying this to Heroku). I followed a tutorial and it worked for me:

```
Remove database adapter gems from your Gemfile, e.g., mysql2, sqlite3, etc

From application.rb, remove require 'rails/all' and add

require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

Delete database.yml, schema.rb and all the migrations
Delete migration checks from test/test_helper.rb
Delete all activerecord related configuration from config/environments
```

However, now - as I am optimizing the processes in my web app (an import csv process), I decided to use delayed jobs using ActiveJob + Resque.

I understand that I needed Redis for Resque and so I installed that and ran the server, however the rake task setup for Resque looks like this:

```
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  Resque.before_fork = Proc.new do |job|
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end
  Resque.after_fork = Proc.new do |job|
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

It seems to need ActiveRecord to do its job (of course since it is mapping to the redis database). And without surprise when I ran this:

```
LOGGING=1 QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work
```

It spews out an error (since ActiveRecord is missing):

```
*** Failed to start worker : #<NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord>
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this was asked awhile ago but the answer here is that you can safely remove the before/after work procs with your own resque.rake

Here is mine:

```
#lib/tasks/resque.rake

require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'

namespace :resque do 
    task setup: :setup_logger do #setup logger includes environment!
        require 'resque'
        require 'resque-scheduler'
    end
 end


#Sets up logging - should only be called from other rake tasks
task setup_logger: :environment do
    logger           = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.level     = Logger.const_get((ENV["LOG_LEVEL"] || "DEBUG").upcase)
    Rails.logger     = logger
end
```